# How to use Single windows form application on multiple machines

Tags: c#, visual-studio

How to use Single windows form application on multiple machines without installing it in all machines? or do i have to install it on all machines?

Comment: You can use [Termianl Services](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc782486(v=ws.10).aspx) or install on each computer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please tag your questions well, Sql Server??. Second, depends on how your application is constructed. If you only have one project, then copying the bin folder with all the files inside should do the work. But if you have more complexity, then you have to make an installer. It is always recommended to make an installer as it takes care of a lot of situations (framework installed, files needed, etc), otherwise you have to take care of that on your own. Not recommended.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Bin folder of project and paste to computer where you want to run it. And directly run YourProgramName.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can do following options:

1) Install project to one machine and create shortcuts on antoher machines, so they will open project installed on first machine

2) Make folder with files and folders in project/bin folder, and you can copy to any machine. But if your project requires something to install this option will not good choice

Comment: "Install project to one machine and create shortcuts on antoher machines" can you give more details on it. I have a winform application which require sql server to be installed along with it. if im planning to install it in a supermarket should i install exe on all machines ?

Comment: You will install SQL DB and project on server machine. and you will open SQL and Remote Desktop ports of server to other clients. And then on client machines you will create a shortcut of project installed on server. Then you can run this project from client machines without installing